# How to add custom properties to the IdentityServer4 PersistedGrantStore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, identityserver4

We are using the default implementation of IPersistedGrantStore with EntityFramework and SQL Server.

I have a requirement to store the IP address (to get 'ballpark' location data on 'sign ins') this table seems the perfect place to do so, as it already stores the client id, datetime, and expiry of the refresh tokens. Is it possible to extend this and add extra properties? If I implement my own version of IPersistedGrantStore, I can't 'break' the contract the interface defines and add extra properties, or even use a derived class (from IdentityServer4.Models.PersistedGrant) as that also wouldn't adhere to the interface.

Is there any way that I can add properties to this table and update the Grant Store implementation to add them when calling StoreAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement your `IPersistedGrantStore` like code below and you have full control over persisted grants, you can add new columns to store.

```
public class PersistStore : IPersistedGrantStore
    {
        private readonly IPersistedGrandStoreService _persistedGrandStore;

        public PersistStore(IPersistedGrandStoreService persistedGrandStore)
        {
            _persistedGrandStore = persistedGrandStore;
        }

        public Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant grant)
        {
            return _persistedGrandStore.AddAsync(grant.ToPersistedGrantModel());
        }

        public async Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
        {
            var grant = await _persistedGrandStore.GetAsync(key);
            return grant.ToPersistedGrant();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId)
        {
            var grants = await _persistedGrandStore.GetAllAsync(subjectId);
            return grants.ToPersistedGrants();
        }

        public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            return _persistedGrandStore.RemoveAsync(key);
        }

        public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)
        {
            return _persistedGrandStore.RemoveAllAsync(subjectId, clientId);
        }

        public Task RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId, string type)
        {
            return _persistedGrandStore.RemoveAllAsync(subjectId, clientId, type);
        }
    }
```